# Synchronize Slider with CurrentTime of Video Dash Plotly

Tags: python, video, slider, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am building a Dash app that will have a video playing and be controlled by a play/pause button.  Above the video, I have a slider which allows a user to skip to any part in the video (10 seconds long).  I want to be able to have the slider move as the video plays.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import os
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_player as player
from flask import Flask, Response
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)


app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div([
                    html.Button('Play/Pause', id='play-button', n_clicks=0),
                ],style={
                    'width':'10%',
                    'display':'inline-block'
                }),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Slider(id='slider',
                               min=0,
                               max=10,
                               step=1,
                               value=0,
                               marks={0: {'label': '0s', 'style': {'color': 'black'}},
                                      2: {'label': '2s', 'style': {'color': 'black'}},
                                      4: {'label': '4s', 'style': {'color': 'black'}},
                                      6: {'label': '6s', 'style': {'color': 'black'}},
                                      8: {'label': '8s', 'style': {'color': 'black'}},
                                      10: {'label': '10s', 'style': {'color': 'black'}}
                                }
                    ),
                ],style={
                    'width':'90%',
                    'display':'inline-block'
                })
               
             ]
        ),
    
        html.Div(
            children=[
                player.DashPlayer(
                    id='video-player',
                    url='https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4',
                    controls=False,
                    width='100%'
                )
            ]
        )    
    ]
)

#Use slider to skip to or "seekTo" different spots in video
@app.callback(Output('video-player', 'seekTo'),
              Input('slider', 'value'))
def set_seekTo(value):
    return value

#Press button to play/pause video 1
@app.callback(
    Output("video-player", "playing"),
    Output("slider","value"),
    Input("play-button", "n_clicks"), 
    State("video-player", "playing"),
    State('slider','value'),
    State("video-player","currentTime")
)
def play_video(n_clicks, playing, value, currentTime):
    value = currentTime
    if n_clicks:
        return not playing, value
    return playing, value




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8050)
```

The play/pause button works just fine, but the functionality of syncing the slider bar to the currentTime of the video is ignored.  No error messages.  What am I missing here?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's because you don't have currentTime or another time interval as an input in of your callbacks. I was able to get the time to sync up with the slider, but I couldn't get it to work in combination with `seekTo`

Comment: Can you share how you got the time to sync with the slider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Note**: I initially wanted to make this a comment as I wasn't able to get the `seekTo` functionality to work in conjunction with synchronizing the time and the slider, but the explanation of my implementation was too long for a comment. Below is listed a way you could update the slider value based on the `currentTime` of the dash player component, but doesn't implement `seekTo`.*

---

#### Implementation

```
import os
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_player as player
from flask import Flask, Response
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.Button("Play/Pause", id="play-button", n_clicks=0),
                    ],
                    style={"width": "10%", "display": "inline-block"},
                ),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        dcc.Slider(
                            id="slider",
                            min=0,
                            max=10,
                            step=1,
                            value=0,
                            marks={
                                0: {"label": "0s", "style": {"color": "black"}},
                                2: {"label": "2s", "style": {"color": "black"}},
                                4: {"label": "4s", "style": {"color": "black"}},
                                6: {"label": "6s", "style": {"color": "black"}},
                                8: {"label": "8s", "style": {"color": "black"}},
                                10: {"label": "10s", "style": {"color": "black"}},
                            },
                        ),
                    ],
                    style={"width": "90%", "display": "inline-block"},
                ),
            ]
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                player.DashPlayer(
                    id="video-player",
                    url="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
                    controls=False,
                    width="100%",
                )
            ]
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("slider", "value"), Input("video-player", "currentTime"))
def update_slider(current_time):
    return current_time


@app.callback(
    Output("video-player", "playing"),
    Input("play-button", "n_clicks"),
    State("video-player", "playing"),
)
def play_video(n_clicks, playing):
    if n_clicks:
        return not playing
    return playing


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8050)
```

#### Explanation

The idea of the above implementation is to create a callback for updating the slider value everytime the `currentTime` interval changes and to create a callback that handles playing and pausing the video when `play-button` is pressed.

Keep in mind here that I'm using `currentTime` as an input, so the callback will get called everytime this value changes. [It seems to change every `40` ms by default](https://github.com/plotly/dash-player). You can change this interval by setting the `intervalCurrentTime` prop on the `DashPlayer`.

Also keep in mind that the slider value will only change every second here, because `step` is set to `1`. So change the `step` value in combination with `intervalCurrentTime` if you want different behavior.